# ImportError: cannot import name 'QColorConstants' from 'PyQt5.QtGui

Tags: python, pyqt5

i have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS python 3.8.10 64bits and i have this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 6, in 
ImportError: cannot import name 'QColorConstants' from 'PyQt5.QtGui' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.abi3.so)

i found this in order to update pyqt from 5.14: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383590/is-it-possible-to-install-python3-pyqt5-5-15-on-ubuntu-20-04

But still it doesn't work

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR
>>> PYQT_VERSION_STR
'5.15.2'
```

Comment: Does that error happen when using the interactive console as you did for the version? Because it seems that you're probably using another version (maybe in a different venv, conda, etc.). Btw, PyQt and Qt version don't always match, you should always use `QT_VERSION_STR` to know the actual Qt version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I ran these commands (the typical one) in a virtual environment of python 3.8.10 in Ubuntu 20.04.4:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

And it installed version `5.15.6`. I recommend to uninstall your package first with

```
pip uninstall pyqt5
```

and then the pip install command.
Alternatively. if you want a specific version of the package (I assume 5.15.5) you can just force it during the installation with

```
pip install pyqt5==5.15.5
```

Anyway, with version `5.15.6` I can do your import.

However, I got your error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QColorConstants' from 'PyQt5.QtGui.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path-here" - ImportError: cannot import name 'QColorConstants' from 'PyQt5.QtGui.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyqt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyqt5'
```

when I tried

```
from pyqt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR

print(PYQT_VERSION_STR)
```

instead of

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR

print(PYQT_VERSION_STR)
```

which gives the correct output.
Check if you import somewhere `pyqt5` instead of `PyQt5`.